# Как создать сценарий для git (bat)

Tags: git, bat

Как можно создать сценарий для git в винде? Гит консоль установил, команда есть, но команда вечно просит логин-пароль. Нужно извращатся писать перехват консоли что б автоматически ввести логин-пароль, или есть какие-то решения по-проще.

Я понял что есть `git push` `git pull` `git commit`

Можно ли привести пример батника, с синхронизацией. 
Т.е. типа git_put.bat который подрубится, сделает commit и push (если не ошибаюсь) и git_get.bat (забрать с гита изменения). Возможно эти два сценария можно обьеденить в один (синхронизация) возможно нет... это уже проще....

Я команды гита ещё не освоил.. Может у кого-то валяются такие сценарии? Поделитесь пожайлуста.

Comment: Если проблема только в том, что нужно постоянно вводить логин и пароль, то советую перейти на ssh. В этом случае вы генерируете пару ключей, открытый ключ один раз отправляете на сервер. После этого сервер всегда будет аутентифицировать вас по этому ключу.

Comment: Пользуюсь git в связке с TortoiseGit. Кто-то из них запоминает логин/пароль и в дальнейшем их не надо постоянно вводить не в командной строке, не через ГУИ.

Comment: Что касается commit и push. То если речь о тематической ветке, тогда ладно. А если речь о master, то это через-чур оптимистичный bat-ник получится. Перед push, хотя бы надо сделать pull...